# CoreBluetooth - How to make device appear in Settings-->Bluetooth with "Not Connected"

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I have a bluetooth application on iOS that connects properly, etc. However, when my peripheral goes out of range, my peripheral disappears from my list in `Settings-->Bluetooth`. However, my Apple Watch, which also communicates via Bluetooth, as well as certain 3rd party products (Withings Weight Scale, JamBox), still appear in the `Settings-->Bluetooth` list with a "Not Connected" message and info button. What do I need to enable in order for my device to appear in this list when not connected? I have already enabled state restoration and that property works well most of the time.

Comment: Do you have a pending "connect" for your device?  Does your device support encryption and therefore bonding/pairing?

Comment: I do have a pending connect, and that works all well and good most of the time, but does not work when I background my app, take my sensor out of range, turn off bluetooth, turn back on bluetooth, and bring the sensor in range. The pending connect is lost and my device does not connect, and when my device is out of range, the device does not list on my Bluetooth Settings page with a "Not Connected" message like the Apple Watch, JamBox, Withings Scale, etc. do. Yes, it does support encryption, but I am unclear what bonding/pairing means. Can you clarify? thanks!